# i accidentally set max connection to 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i accidentally set max connections of root to 1 and i cant do nothing in MySQL, i'm running MySQL on a WAMP server and i'm logging in as client who has no Privileges but usage.. can it be fixed?

Comment: From what I know `max_connections` doesn't apply for Super User. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html. You should be able to always change the connection from Super User.

Comment: You can edit `my.cnf` and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out i should go to the table mysql.user as any user and change the admin max_connections